# html/jquery - Nested forms for file upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, xhtml, nested-forms

I have a products page that needs to have a file upload midway through a form that will run via iframes/ajax through a JQuery Plugin.

However, to do this I need nested forms which obviously is very bad practice and will not validate.

What options do I have to at least make it appear to be the same?

Do I need to use JQuery to seperate the forms somehow? Or will using an iframe fix the issue?

Thanks!?

Comment: You cannot have a form inside a form. Its a html restriction.

Comment: In java when submitting a form to a servlet, we can check whether the field is a form field or upload data. I am not sure about your backend, but something like that may have exist in your backend.

Comment: @ItsNotMe Well i'm using PHP and if I was posting the data I would simply use the $_FILES superglobal. I want to allow users to upload files before submitting the main form as sic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If midway you mean visually, then you can have a html where you have ..., then  or even ..., and you can position the iframe with css, so it looks like it's in the middle of the form. If this is what you want, and you need more help, we need more details to help :)

Comment: Yes, visually I want it to look like its in the same form as I need to pass the image ids returned as part of the main form. Its almost like a sub-form as such. I am using the plugin made by malsup here http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload, Processing will done using PHP

Comment: What I want to know really is using an iframe to do this really the best option?

Comment: I had a look to that plugin page, and in the demo I don't see an iframe. I guess it builds an iframe for posting, but in "your" markup there doesn't need to be one.

Comment: Yes, i've never needed to do file uploads 'asynchronously' before so this is all new to me. Usually sending the POST request normally has been enough.

Comment: I had another thought. The demo has a tiny form for uploading, that'll be like your sub-form, but you'll have the other one around, so for that you might need the iframe. HOWEVER: what about not having a big form around? You can have input, select, textarea fields all over, and when you click on a button, you can "collect" the data and post it with an ajax call. Actually this might be even nicer!

Comment: Good idea! I didn't notice that. I can still achieve what I want by using AJAX.